# WCF Notification and Callback with clients

Tags: asp.net, wcf, wcf-security, wcf-client

[image]

As shown above am trying to achieve the same. In detail :

1. I have a WCF service on Public IP and WCF clients with internet access

   **Central Service** : It supposed to check any price change at central node and notify the same to the WCF clients.

   **Client service** : On notification from central service the client will perform Pulling data from the server and acknowledegs the same back.
2. *Firstly I wanted my central service to know about clients and send notifications to the clients, My question is how can I see them(WCF clients) ? even as a subscriber list what data of the client should I have to notify the WCF clients.*
3. *Secondly the client needs to update the server oncompletion of a particular task.*

I am looking for anwsers moreover on suggestion of pattern or any ideas on how to achieve the same. Any links will highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Firstly I wanted my central service to know about clients and send
>   notifications to the clients, My question is how can I see them(WCF
>   clients) ? even as a subscriber list what data of the client should I
>   have to notify the WCF clients.

Looks like you want to implement a publisher-subscriber architecture, you achieve the requirements you listed through callbacks. A standard way to achieve this would be to have your clients subscribe to your central service. Upon subscription, your central service would keep a list of your connected clients (you represent clients as callback instances) in a dictionary (this is one way, a static list is another way). For example:

`static Dictionary<INotificationCallback, string> subscribers = new Dictionary<INotificationCallback, string>();`

When clients subscribe to your service, you could add each callback instance to your subscribers dictionary (you actually store each instance of the callbacks-clients that connect to your service along with their username, which is the string vlaue in the dictionary).

Your central service would also need to define a callback contract (here our callback contract is `INotificationCallback`), so that it can invoke some operations on the clients that connect to it. This will allow your central service to send whatever data it wants to the clients, i.e. whenever a price change occurs.

> Secondly the client needs to update the server on completion of a
>   particular task.

Just define another operation contract on your central service that your clients would call on successful completion of a task. How you keep track of which tasks were completed and how to keep track of them is entirely up to you.

Somebody asked a similar question recently, and I think if you take a look at [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11147968/189756) you'd find it quite helpful. Also when I wanted to learn the pub-sub pattern and duplex communication in WCF, I found [this article](http://tomasz.janczuk.org/2009/11/pubsub-sample-with-wcf-nettcp-protocol.html) very helpful. However if you're looking to do this over the internet, you shouldn't use `netTcpBinding`, rather a HTTP based binding that supports duplex, such as `wsDualHttpBinding` or `HttpPollingDuplex` for Silverlight clients.

Update: Some more useful articles/samples per your request:

1. [Design Patterns: List-Based Publish-Subscribe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752254.aspx)
2. [WCF Implementation of the Publisher/Subscriber Model](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22796/WCF-Implementation-of-the-Publisher-Subscriber-Mod)
3. [A WCF-WPF Chat Application](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25261/A-WCF-WPF-Chat-Application)

The last one is a chat application, it essentially uses duplex, which is a very similar service architecture to what you're looking for.

Comment: :+1 Aweseome explanation :) , +1 for your other anwser too,It has cleared all the doubts which I had, One more thing I was looking for some samples for this pattern pub-sub on internet, Have found most of them are using `netTcp`, Any reasons that i should not use it? Also note that my Clients are esp standalone WCF clients not any web clients...

Comment: @user1042031 you're welcome. `netTcpBinding` has great performance, and supports duplex, I guess that's a reason a lot of samples use it. However (from what I've gathered) it's generally not advisable to use `netTcpBinding` across HTTP as the ports it uses are usually blocked by firewalls (on the internet your service messages will travel through many routers and firewalls beyond your control). Having said that, I did test out `netTcpBinding` across HTTP and it worked for me (note the word test-I haven't used it in production) after I forwarded port 808 to the host computer on our router.

Comment: Thanks for that Info.. your anwser really helps me to start off my part from where I was confused and got stuck..Will Comment If I need any little more info.. Hope u dont mind asking u even if i tick this as my anwser :)

Comment: .. Kindly refer me to few helpful links

Comment: @user1042031 take a look at answer again, I added some more links.

Comment: Kindly check this Qn which is in continuation of this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11859585/security-negotiation-exception-wcf-hosted-on-publicip