# Asynchronous message sending WCF

Tags: wcf, asynchronous, async-await, wcf-binding

The addMessage method asynchronously sends messages to clients.

The problem is that those who send it receive it themselves

That is, the client hears himself

```
            public void AddMessage(byte[] message)
            {
                
                  IAsyncMessageCallback other = OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<IAsyncMessageCallback>();
                  other.BeginOnMessageAdded(message, DateTime.Now, delegate (IAsyncResult ar)
                        {
                            other.EndOnMessageAdded(ar);
                        }, null);
                

            }
```

I tried to implement it in the following way:

```
            public void AddMessage(byte[] message)
            {
                lock (subscribers)
                {
                    var connection = OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<IAsyncMessageCallback>();

                    string user;
                    if (!subscribers.TryGetValue(connection, out user))
                        return;
                    foreach (var other in subscribers.Keys)
                    {
                        //Console.WriteLine(other + " " + connection);
                        if (other == connection)
                            continue;
                        Console.WriteLine(other + " " + connection);
                        other.BeginOnMessageAdded(message, DateTime.Now, delegate (IAsyncResult ar)
                        {
                            other.EndOnMessageAdded(ar);
                        }, null);
                        Console.WriteLine(message.Length);
                    }
                }
              }
```

But this leads to terrible brakes

Thank you in advance

The essence of the problem:
1.When more than two users enter, the chat starts to hang (a very long delay appears), and then the connection is broken: The communication object System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel cannot be used for communication, since its operation is interrupted

If you remove the foreach loop, there will be no breaks and the chat will work calmly with ten users, but the message will be sent to everyone (that is, I will hear my voice in the chat)

Everything works, but with two users. If more come in then System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel cannot be used for communication, since its operation is interrupted

```
 public void SendMessage(byte[] message)
     {
         var connection = OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<IChatClient>();
         string user;
         if (!_users.TryGetValue(connection, out user))
             return;
          foreach (var other in _users.Keys)
         {
             if (other == connection)
                 continue;
             other.RecievMessage(user, message);
             Console.WriteLine(message.Length);
         }
     }
```

If you remove the foreach loop, ten users can come in, but they will hear themselves because the server sends this message to everyone indiscriminately.

if the person who sent the video is the current subscriber they don't send the video to THAT subscriber.

How to implement it?

```
public class StackOverflow_5979252
{
    [ServiceContract(Name = "IMessageCallback")]
    public interface IAsyncMessageCallback
    {
        [OperationContract(AsyncPattern = true)]
        IAsyncResult BeginOnMessageAdded(string msg, DateTime timestamp, AsyncCallback callback, object asyncState);
        void EndOnMessageAdded(IAsyncResult result);
    }
    [ServiceContract(CallbackContract = typeof(IAsyncMessageCallback))]
    public interface IMessage
    {
        [OperationContract]
        void AddMessage(string message);
    }
    [ServiceBehavior(IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]
    public class Service : IMessage
    {
        public void AddMessage(string message)
        {
            IAsyncMessageCallback callback = OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<IAsyncMessageCallback>();
            callback.BeginOnMessageAdded(message, DateTime.Now, delegate(IAsyncResult ar)
            {
                callback.EndOnMessageAdded(ar);
            }, null);
        }
    }
    class MyClientCallback : IAsyncMessageCallback
    {
        public IAsyncResult BeginOnMessageAdded(string msg, DateTime timestamp, AsyncCallback callback, object asyncState)
        {
            Action<string, DateTime> act = (txt, time) => { Console.WriteLine("[{0}] {1}", time, txt); };
            return act.BeginInvoke(msg, timestamp, callback, asyncState);
        }

        public void EndOnMessageAdded(IAsyncResult result)
        {
            Action<string,DateTime> act = (Action<string,DateTime>)((System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.AsyncResult)result).AsyncDelegate;
            act.EndInvoke(result);
        }
    }
    static Binding GetBinding()
    {
        return new NetTcpBinding(SecurityMode.None);
    }
    public static void Test()
    {
        string baseAddress = "net.tcp://" + Environment.MachineName + ":8000/Service";
        ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(Service), new Uri(baseAddress));
        host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IMessage), GetBinding(), "");
        host.Open();
        Console.WriteLine("Host opened");

        InstanceContext instanceContext = new InstanceContext(new MyClientCallback());
        DuplexChannelFactory<IMessage> factory = new DuplexChannelFactory<IMessage>(instanceContext, GetBinding(), new EndpointAddress(baseAddress));
        IMessage proxy = factory.CreateChannel();
        proxy.AddMessage("Hello world");

        Console.Write("Press ENTER to close the host");
        Console.ReadLine();
        ((IClientChannel)proxy).Close();
        factory.Close();
        host.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you can provide more detailed error information to help you solve the problem better.

Comment: 1.When more than two users in chat toom, the chat starts to lags, and after then connection is broken: "The communication object System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel cannot be used for communication, since its operation is interrupted" 

2.If i remove the foreach, there will be no lags and the chat will work good with 10+ users, but the message from me will be sent to everyone (including me. I will hear my voice in the chat)

Comment: You can try to find the method through this article:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11142373/wcf-how-to-write-a-publisher-subscriber-service-that-publishes-only-to-specifi